Karma concept is this?
Namasté to everybody. I'm new in this forum.
I starting to dive into Advaita Vedanta a couple of months ago. Its philosophy, theology, spiritualy and practice seem to me very inspiring.
But a concept I having a hard time with is Karma.. Everywhere you see comments that western's view of Karma is mistaken. But always the explanaitions (I've read some comments like Adi Shankara's own study on the Upanishads, or simple expositions like Swami Sarvapriyananda's informative videos) fall on the 'Just world' fallacy.
Maybe I'm wrong and not understanding the concept properly, but what I'm getting that dharma Karma's concept is just the old cognitive bias that good persons will achieve good results, and bad persons have what they deserve..
Criticism pointing to these fallacies are always being answered with 'God works in misterious ways' explanations (the rule of Karma belongs to Ishvara, we are not suitable for understanding Ishvara's decisions). That's the best case escenarios. Other answers to the criticism appeal to the "cheat" of stating that the results of Karma can be seen in the next life.. what of course is a worse phallacy because this position takes cover under the impossibility to refute a future nobodody knows. I'm quite surprised about these concepts, specially under Advaita's developments.

Welcome Martin. I don't know if I understand your question fully. Think of Karma as being similar to a seed turning into a tree and then bearing fruits. It may takes years. Karmas don't always give results overnight, rather they span over lifetimes and once planted (positive and negative mental conditionings) take a long time to reverse / uproot.

I) Your first question Namasté to everybody. I'm new in this forum. I starting to dive into Advaita Vedanta a couple of months ago........ good persons will achieve good results, and bad persons have what they deserve.
You will easily understand, as a student of Advaida Vedānta, that there is no good person or bad person categorization(according to Advaidam) because we are all the projections of the same Brahman(The Absolute) through Māyā as upādhi. Only the intension or motive of the acts committed determine whether it is good karma or not. According to the 20th sloka(verse) of Brahmajnānāvalimālā (ब्रह्मज्ञानावलीमाला), written by Shri Ādi Sankarāchāryā:

ब्रह्म सत्यं जगन्मिथ्या जीवो ब्रह्मैव नापरः ।
अनेन वेद्यं सच्छास्त्रमिति वेदान्तडिण्डिमः ॥ २०॥.

brahma satyam jaganmithya jīvo brahmaiva nāparah
anena vedyam sacchāstramiti vedāntadindimah ॥ 20 ॥.

Brahman(ब्रह्मन्/The Absolute) is alone real(सत्); 
the world(जगत्/Jagat) is Mithya(मिथ्या/Illusion);
Ĵiva(जीव) is non-different from Brahman. ॥ 20 ॥


Observe that Ĵiva is non-different from Brahman because both are cethana (चेतना/Conscious Principle). As long as media of reflection(Māyā) is asuddha(impure), Ĵiva will be under the sway of three gunas (sattva, rajas and tamas). When Sattva predominates, Ĵiva will be incapable of committing bad karma! Therefore, it is the mix of three gunas will determine the nature of our personality to commit punya(virtuous) or papa(sinful) acts.
II) Your second question Criticism pointing to these fallacies are always being answered with 'God works in misterious ways' explanations (the rule of Karma belongs to Ishvara, we are not suitable for understanding Ishvara's decisions). That's the best case escenarios.
Before plunging in to the ocean of advaida vedāntam, knowledge of Shat Darshana (Sānkhya and Yoga) will make you to ignore confidently such statements God works in misterious ways all together. Please study the following thoroughly in the order they appear:

Sānkhya Darshana(साङ्ख्य दर्शन), authored by Kapila Maharishi(महऋषि कपिल), which delineates an atheistic and strongly dualist exposition of Purusha and Prakriti (परिणामवादम्). Read Samkhya Philosophy [Containing (1) Samkhya-pravachanasutram, with Vritti of Aniruddha, and the Bhasya of Vijnanabhiksu and Extracts from the Vrittisara of Mahadeva Vedantin; (2) Tatvasamasa; (3) Samkhyakarika; (4) Panchasikhasutram] by Nandalal Sihna [Translator].

Yoga Darshana(योग दर्शन), authored by Patanjali Maharishi (महऋषि पतञ्जलि), which is a school emphasizing meditation, contemplation and liberation.

Mukya Dasopanishads(मुख्य दशोपनिषद्): Knowledge of Ten Mukya Upanishads is core to digest Vedānta and the slokas of Bhagavad Gīta effortlessly which are (1) Isā(ईशा), (2) Kena(केन), (3) Katha(कठ), (4) Prasna(प्रस्न), (5) Mundaka(मुण्डक), (6) Māndūkya(माण्डूक्य), (7) Taittirīya(तैत्तिरीय), (8) Aitareya(ऐतरेय), (9) Chāndogya(छान्दोग्य) and (10) Brihadāranyaka(बृहदारण्यक). Read Mukya Upanishad published by Ramakrishna Math iStore.


Sānkhya Darshana is atheistic and ignores God(Īsvara) which explains the role of Prakriti(three gunas) in the formation of universe. Yoga Darshana follows Sānkhya Darshana but accepts Īsvara for self-realization and mental discipline. Study of Upanishads are vital to understand vedānta.
Yoga Darshana's parlance of karma is Samskāra(संस्कार/Latent Impressions) which functions, without intervention of Īsvara. If it is so, then how do they decide the embodiment, the Life-span and the experiences needed for forthcoming reincarnation of an entity? According to Ashtānga Yoga (अष्टाङ्गयोग) authored by Maharishi Patanjali(महऋषि पतञ्जलि), the basis for Punarjanma (पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) is Karmāsaya(कर्माशय/Latent Impressions of Action), also known as Prārabdha Karma in vedānta philosophy, which causes Trivipāka (embodiment/Jāti, longevity/Āyush and experience/Bhoga) for every incarnation of entities.
III) Your third and final question Other answers........I'm quite surprised about these concepts, specially under Advaita's developments.
Since your question is about karma and next life, let us look into the relationship between them as follows:

At the time of death, the subset of Sanchita Karma which are ripe
and ready to sprout, will decide the suitable embodiment to
experience and a life-span. This subset is known as Prārabdha karma.
In Yoga parlance, a subset of samskaras stored in Kārana Sarīra as seeds,
which are ripe and ready to sprout is called known as  Karmāsaya (कर्माशय/Latent Impressions of Action) responsible for Punarjanma (पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) by deciding embodiment and life-span.
Bhagavān Krishna says in Bhagavath Geetha [8.6] about taking future
birth that depends upon your thought at the time of death. If one
thinks about a bird at the time of death, then he will assume a bird
form in the forthcoming birth [Refer my Quora Post on Jada
Bharatha(जडभरत)]. If you utter ‘Govinda’ at the moment of
death, you will reach the Padāravinda(पदारविन्द/Lotus Feet) of Lod
Krishna!

First one Karma is vedantic parlance, second one Samskāras is yoga terminology and final one Last thought at time of death is from Bhagavath Gita. These three are various angle through which the same truth (punarjanma/reincarnation) is perceived!
If someone says the results of Karma can be seen in the next life, then it means that if result of good karmas or bad karmas committed in the present life escape from experiencing in this birth, then it will be definitely experienced in some future birth when seeds of those samskaras are stronger enough ready to sprout.
OP says "takes cover under the impossibility to refute a future nobody knows. I'm quite surprised about these concepts, specially under Advaita's developments".
Basic rule is Seeds of stronger Samskāras gets precedence over weaker one. Suppose a Ĵiva enjoys cruel acts, then the samskara corresponding to that notion will be stronger enough to sprout and decide forthcoming birth. Contrarily, Ĵiva has inclination towards charity and helping and if that samskara grows stronger and stronger, then that will sprout to decide the next birth resulting in elevated birth such as a Deva. As Bhagavan Krishna in BG [8.6] says at death bed, the thoughts in the mind determines future birth, in yoga parlance, the thoughts at the moment of death reflect the strongest samskaras(stored as seeds) which are ripe and ready to sprout.
